# Как синхронизовать воспроизведение на браузерах для совместного просмотра фильмов?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, http, rtsp, hls

Есть задача сделать сайт для совместного просмотра фильмов. Видео просто лежит на сервере, вопрос в том, как синхронизовать его воспроизведение на браузерах пользователей. В перспективе нужна возможность перемотки и остановки воспроизведения видео.

Бекенд хотелось бы реализовать на java, но не принципиально.

Какой стек протоколов/технологий посоветуете?

Comment: spring + синхронизация времени через stomp (отправляем текущее время друг другу и сравниваем друг у друга). Другое дело что такое синхронизация в вашем понимании? Если у кого-то видео подвисло, то ожидаем его или перематываем его?

Comment: Задержка у одного клиента не должна останавливать остальных, то есть если у одного клиента видео отстает, то мы должны его перемотать. Не подскажите, какой протокол для трансляции видео стоит использовать?

Comment: через hls) progressive download тут не пойдет, ведь нужно еще и в разном качестве, да?

Comment: Думаю да. Из последних идей использовать для этого ffmpeg, и вызывать его из spring

Comment: Посмотрите еще nimble streamer, он из коробки умеет mp4 -> hls с s3 серверов

Answer (score 0):

**Вероятно**, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [Spring](https://spring.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Если **Вы** собираетесь делать синхронизацию между пользователями по остановке и перемотке видео, то тогда вам скорее всего понадобится использовать протокол **WebSocket**. Думаю, что самая удобная платформа для написания **WebSocket** сервера — **NodeJS**, но есть и другие варианты, такие как библиотека **Workerman** на **PHP** или если предпочитаете **C#**, то посмотрите на **ASP.NET Core SignalR**.

**P.S.** вместо **ВебСокетов** на **NodeJS** можно также использовать библиотеку **Socket IO**, которая как раз и основана на **ВебСокетах** и других технологиях. Рекомендую вам посмотреть различия между **ВебСокетами** и **Socket IO**.